# XSLT multi case

Tags: xml, xslt

From the begining i have

```
<GTD>
  <BLOCK>
    <G_47_1_1>1010</G_47_1_1>
    <G_47_1_2>6680520.46</G_47_1_2>
    <G_47_1_3>15000R</G_47_1_3>
    <G_47_1_4>15000.00</G_47_1_4>
    <G_47_1_5>PER</G_47_1_5>
    <G_47_2_1>5010</G_47_2_1>
    <G_47_2_2>86723.30</G_47_2_2>
    <G_47_2_3>18%</G_47_2_3>
    <G_47_2_4>15610.19</G_47_2_4>
    <G_47_2_5>RTY</G_47_2_5>
    <G_47_3_1>3010</G_47_2_1>
    <G_47_4_2>86723.30</G_47_2_2>
    <G_47_5_3>18%</G_47_2_3>
    <G_47_6_4>15610.19</G_47_2_4>
    <G_47_7_5>GH</G_47_2_5>
  </BLOCK>
  <BLOCK>
    ...
  </BLOCK>
<GTD>
```

and i need to get result information

```
<GTD>
  <LINE>
    <VAR_1_1>
      1010
    </VAR_1_1>
    <VAR_1_2>
      value of G_47_*_2 is G_47_*_1 = 1010
    </VAR_1_2>
    <VAR_1_3>
      value of G_47_*_3 is G_47_*_1 = 1010
    </VAR_1_3>
    <VAR_1_4>
      value of G_47_*_4 is G_47_*_1 = 1010
    </VAR_1_4>
    <VAR_2_1>
      2010
    </VAR_2_1>
    <VAR_2_2>  ... the same with 2010 and 5010...
  </LINE>
</GTD>
```

as far as i understand there should be used **xsl:template match**.

i know how to get one value inside of one block of **teplate match** but how i can use it for several values in one array?

### UPDATED:

The logic of the process:

- I have 12 elements in source xml (3 block by 4 lines)
- Each block can be assigned to one code 2010 3010 or 5010 in
  **G_47_*_1** element
- Order of this codes can be different, not all of them can be present
  (e.g. only 2010 in G_47_1_1, or 5010 in G_47_1_1 and 2010 in
  G_47_2_1)
- In target xml i need to fill 12 element (3 block by 4 lines)
- Order of this elements fixed (4 elements for 2010, after 3010, after
  5010)
- All of them present even if there is not such elements in source XML

Now i use this construction

```
<VAR_1_1>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="../G_47_1_1/text()='1010'">
      <xsl:value-of select="../G_47_1_1/text()" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="../G_47_2_1/text()='1010'">
      <xsl:value-of select="../G_47_2_1/text()" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="../G_47_3_1/text()='1010'">
      <xsl:value-of select="../G_47_3_1/text()" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</CustomsFeeCode>
```

But i need to copy it 12 times (for each element in target XML)
It works. But I think it's not right

Comment: Please explain the logic behind the requested transformation.

Comment: Please, find my update in main question

Comment: So, you mean: if node name is X and its contents is `1010`, get that contents (which, in that case, is always `1010`). and then name the new node `VAR_` + `X` (right part of X, actually).

Comment: in fact yes. so, firstly i need to find which `G_47_X_1` contain value `1010`. after I need to put in `VAR_1_Y` value of `G_47_X_Y` (`Y` from 1 to 4) and repeat this operation for `3010` and `5010`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This repetition can be rewritten, as you already suspected. Change (fixed by making it valid XML):

```
<VAR_1_1>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="../G_47_1_1/text()='1010'">
      <xsl:value-of select="../G_47_1_1/text()" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="../G_47_2_1/text()='1010'">
      <xsl:value-of select="../G_47_2_1/text()" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="../G_47_3_1/text()='1010'">
      <xsl:value-of select="../G_47_3_1/text()" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</VAR_1_1>
```

By:

```
<VAR_1_1>
    <xsl:variable name="g47" select="../*[starts-with(local-name(.), 'G_47')][text() = '1010']" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$g47" />
    <xsl:if test="not($g47)">0</xsl:if>
</VAR_1_1>
```

(untested)

If you can switch to XSLT 2.0, the predicate can use a regular expression, instead of `starts-with`, i.e.: `matches(local-name(), 'G_47_[0-9]+_1')`.

### Update (after your question was updated)

> Each block can be assigned to one code 2010 3010 or 5010 in G_47_*_1 element

In your apply-templates, add an `xsl:with-param` and in your matching template, add an `xsl:param`. Make three `xsl:apply-templates` where you change the param into 2010, 3010, 5010.

> Order of this codes can be different, not all of them can be present (e.g. only 2010 in G_47_1_1, or 5010 in G_47_1_1 and 2010 in G_47_2_1)

This is irrelevant in XSLT, unless you mean you want them sorted in which case you should add `xsl:sort`.

> In target xml i need to fill 12 element (3 block by 4 lines)

Ok. You probably want a dynamic creation of element name. Use `<xsl:element name="{...}" /> and add the XPath expression that creates the element name in the place of the dots. Have a look at the functions`substring-before`and`substring-after`. In XSLT 2.0, simply use a regular expression with`replace()`.

> Order of this elements fixed (4 elements for 2010, after 3010, after 5010)

This is fixed by using the three apply-templates approach, see first point above.

> All of them present even if there is not such elements in source XML

This is fixed by the `xsl:if` in my example code above if the element is empty. If the element is not there, it is typically easier to do a two-way transform: first the structure, then fill in the missing parts. In XSLT 1.0 you will need the `exslt:node-set` function, in XSLT 2.0 you can simply re-apply to the temporary result set of your first transform. All within the same stylesheet. Be aware to switch modes in case names match with the original source.

Comment: I write in BizTalk. It can work only with XSLT 1.0 in my version. Also, as far as i understand i will need 12 vars, yes?

Comment: And how it will be for `VAR_1_2` for example?

Comment: @V.Plotnikov, I have answered your questions. I'm sorry, I won't do the full task for you as that is not in StackOverflow's nature. The idea is to help you along (I can highly recommend spending a few hours with the video tutorial of [Dimitre Novatchev's on XSLT at Pluralsight](http://www.maxfeel.org/tutorials-list/pluralsight-xslt-2-0-and-1-0-foundations-with-dimitre-novatchev_1v174.html). Money and time well spent!).

Comment: On the vars: no, only one, as written above.